# bash if else statement

Tags: bash, if-statement

This is so simple but I cannot get it to work.  I want to do a simple if else statement in ssh bash script.  here's my code below:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo -n "enter what type of logs. (ie. cpanel, apache) "
read type
if [$type == cpanel]
then
LOGTYPES ="error, access"
else
LOGTYPES ="error, access, suphp, suexec"
fi

echo -n "enter which log to tail (ie. $LOGTYPES) "
read logs
echo -n "enter last number of lines to view. (ie. 10, 5000 etc) "
read lines

tail -$lines /usr/local/$type\/logs/$logs\_log
```

I've tried everything and I keep getting this error:

```
[~]# /apachetail
enter what type of logs. (ie. cpanel, apache) cpanel
/apachetail: line 5: [cpanel: command not found
/apachetail: line 9: LOGTYPES: command not found
enter which log to tail (ie. )
```

I've tried the following methods, none work:

```
    if [$type -eq cpanel]
    if [$type -eq cpanel];
    if [$type == cpanel];
    if [$type = cpanel]
    if [$type = cpanel];
    if ["$type" = cpanel]
    if ["$type" = cpanel];
    if ["$type" == cpanel]
    if ["$type" == cpanel];
    if ["$type" -eq cpanel];
    if ["$type" -eq cpanel]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change

```
if [$type == cpanel]
```

to

```
if [ "$type" = "cpanel" ]
```

and

```
   LOGTYPES ="error, access"
```

to

```
   LOGTYPES="error, access"
```

Any assignment has to be without spaces around the = (assignment operator).

Comment: ahh so it's all about the spacing mainly.  Thanks that worked!

Comment: Additionally double '=' in "[ a == b ]" is a bash extension, either use #!/bin/bash in first line or "[ a = b ]".

Comment: @sven30: It's important to remember that in the shell command language `[` is a command and not syntax. It's a program you execute and it takes arguments; it's also called `test` (man test). Since it's not syntax bash can't tell what it is unless it's its own token delimited by whitespace or other syntax.

Comment: @Sorpigal Interesting, but does that mean "]" is just sugar to make it look nice?

Answer (score 3):

The `LOGTYPES =` should be `LOGTYPES=` - note the missing space.
And `[$type == cpanel]` should be `[ $type == cpanel ]` - note the *added* space.

Comment: You probably also want to quote the conditional so that it's  `if [[ "$type" == "cpanel" ]]`. `[[` is a more advanced version of `[`. It's also always a good idea to insert spaces in the conditional, so that there's a space between the bracket and the conditional on each side.

Comment: Full quotes within `[[` are not necessary.